# Mule - separating sub-flows into their own flow files

Tags: mule

We have a Mule flow which consists of multiple sub-flows - in order to manage this better we'd like to copy the sub flows to their own individual files. At run time I get the following error I am trying to figure out.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ParentFlow': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.config.spring.factories.ScatterGatherRouterFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.config.spring.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'childflow' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
... 20 more
```

This is the config:

```
<flow name="ParentFlow" doc:name="ParentFlow">
    <flow-ref name="childFlow" doc:name="childFlow" />
</flow>
<sub-flow name="childflow" doc:name="childflow">
</sub-flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the config you have provided it can be seen that the name of the ChildFlow is not spelt correctly (case).

The name of the subflow is "childflow" whereas the name being referred is "childFlow"

Use the correct name "childflow" in the flow ref and it should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code? maybe sub-flow isn't referenced correctly or is pointing to an undefined subflow.

Comment: <flow name="ParentFlow" doc:name="ParentFlow">
<flow-ref name="childFlow" doc:name="childFlow" />
</flow>

<sub-flow name="childflow" doc:name="childflow">
</sub-flow>

Comment: try to define subflow before the flow definition

Comment: and ref flow inside ParentFlow

Comment: This issue is resolved - actually what was happening was that I was trying to run a JUnit and kept on getting errors - I thought the flow configuration was incorrect but in fact what needs to end up happening is that getConfigResources needs to have a comma separated list of flows.